# How to embed javascript element of type fact-box in Apple-news-formate

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, iframe, apple-news

I was trying to embed an element of the type `fact-box` in the apple-news-template.

We have a JSON `iframe` element of type `fact-box` and under the body, we have `<div></div>` and `<script src= "link to a .js file"></script>` tags I want to make use of this script `.js` in the apple news template to render the article.

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed with this? Thank you in advance.